# Redirect opened TCP connection

Tags: c++, qt, redirect, tcp, p2p

Is it possible to redirect an opened TCP connection to a third device?

For example I have two clients which are both connected to a central server. Both initiated the communication. They cannot accept any connections from outside the internet because the router's firewall is blocking them.

What if they want to connect to each other: is it possible to redirect the two connections with the server to become one peer-to-peer connection between the clients? (I have a feeling that this is not possible) My program allows that both devices can work as a TCP server, just firewalls are blocking them.

Currently I am using two solutions to communicate between the two clients. One is using UPnP port mappings, the other that messages sent to server are repeated and transmitted to the clients.

Is there any other solution? I am especially interested in methods which are using C++, Qt and Linux.

Comment: Your best solution is probably port-forwarding on the firewalls, but you could take a look at [TCP hole punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching) and [STUN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot redirect already opened TCP connections to another device, because in this case the endpoints of the connection would need to change - but the endpoint (ip+port) is an essential part of the connection. So you could only transfer the data you received at the server from one connection to the other and back, or you could try to make the two parties connect directly to each other from start with TCP hole punching like mentioned in a comment already. But this will only work for simple NAT setups.

Simple port forwarding at the server will not work for already established connections, because you would have to rewrite not only sender and receiver of all packets (e.g. NAT) but also rewrite the sequence numbers etc so they match the other established connection. So you would need to do the forwarding in user space or inside the kernel at the connection level and not the packet level with techniques like socket splicing.